# Skype 'Installing Purchase'

Tags: installation, 12.10, software-center, skype

I'm trying to install Skype on my 64bit Ubuntu 12.10 machine through the software center, but after clicking install it just keeps on saying "Installing Purchase" instead of actually downloading Skype.

After a few minutes it just stops as it times out or whatever. Anybody know what this would happen?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I did was go onto the Skype website and downloaded it from there. Then once I ran it, the 'Buy' button changed to 'Install'. It then carried on installing and finished succesfully

Comment: Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with the Skype install on 12.10 at the moment. The powers that be are working on it. Not sure of the bug number in LP.